# Dockerfile build from parent directory

Tags: python, docker, celery, dockerfile

I have a python application which uses celery workers which I would like to dockerise. Unfortunately, both python and Celery are using the same code base. Although they have to be separate containers for easier scaling. If I build them separately and run the containers it works fine. The problem starts when I introduce docker-compose, therefore I can't swap the dockerfiles out in the code folder and the containers need to be built from outside of the folder. The folder structure is the following:

```
/application
    /application-build
       Dockerfile
    /celery-build
       Dockerfile
    /code
       application.py
       otherfiles.py
```

I have been digging around for a bit now and unfortunately, as far as I know files from the parent directory can't be copied in the dockerfile. Although I would like to copy the same code into both of the containers. 
*(Mind that the following dockerfiles are not the exact ones I use.)*

Dockerfile1:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD /code .
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3.6", "application.py"]
```

Dockerfile2:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD /code .
COPY /code/requirements.txt .
RUN python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["celery","-A application.celery", "worker","work1@host"]
```

One solution I see is to reorganise the folders so the code directory is always the child of the dockerfile's directory like so:

```
/application
   /application-build
      Dockerfile
      /celery-build
         Dockerfile
         /code
            application.py
            otherfiles.py
```

Although it doesn't look clever at all.

Comment: you can use `-f` on docker build to set path to a Dockerfile from parent directory , like `docker build -f /path/to/Dockerfile .`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no problem. In `Dockerfile` you cant get out (access parent folder) of **build context**, not `Dockerfile's` folder.

Leave you structure as it was, and explicitly specify path to `Dockerfile`:

```
docker build -t app -f application-build/Dockerfile . 
docker build -t celery -f celery-build/Dockerfile .
```

And inside your `Dockerfiles` remember that path is `/application`. So you can easily copy:

**Dockerfile**

```
...
COPY code /code
...
```

Answer (score 8):

Supplementing grapes's answer with a Docker Compose equivalent to the `docker build` commands:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  application:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: application-build/Dockerfile

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: celery-build/Dockerfile
```

```sh
# Run this command in the directory of your `docker-compose.yml` file
# (Which is this question's case would be /application/docker-compose.yml)
docker-compose build
```

When each Dockerfile builds, it will use `/application` as its build context.