# Mounting dir that is outside docker context

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I'm trying to use BuildKit `RUN --mount=type=bind` to mount a directory that is two levels up from the docker context dir. Here is a simplified dir structure.

```
project   (dir)
   app    (dir)
   docker (dir)
      docker-compose.yaml (file)
      some-dir1 (dir)
      app (dir)
         Dockerfile (file)
         some-file  (file)
```

`project/app` is the dir containing the java project build with gradle. `project/docker/app` is a docker context of the image that will contain the app.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM gradle:8.3.0-jdk17-alpine as builder
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/home/gradle/app/,source="../../app/",rw \
    cd /home/gradle/app/ && \
    gradle clean && \
    gradle bootJar
```

When I'm trying to build docker image I get the error that docker doesn't see `../../app` dir.

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 2f6eb37e-c9dd-424b-bc15-b41d19994e1c::eg16xi09kr6tsssono9tcri5e: "/app": not found
```

Is it possible to mount dir from outside of the docker context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile build from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110783/dockerfile-build-from-parent-directory)

Comment: Not really. This is a workaround, not the solution. It requires additional parameters to docker command. It would be great to pass only the build subcommand to docker.

Comment: Well, the answer is "no, you can't access files outside the build context", that would be somehow a security issue. You have to somehow change your build context to include the files you need.